# IS it common for mobile data to stop working but normal phone reception to be fine?

Tags: mobile-data

So I've got a sony xperia z3 compact and it's only a couple of months old.

So far, it's been great but today I noticed that the mobile internet doesn't work. The thing is though my phone reception is fine - I can dial people without getting problems - it's just that when I'm not within a WIFI zone, I have no data.

I've rang up my mobile network provider and they say my data is activated. The phone itself is from overseas but I'm fairly sure, the phone's mobile data has worked before - it's only stopped working recently.

I'm trying to figure out if it's a hardware fault in my phone and I'm hoping it's not because it would be difficult and lengthy to get it replaced. Is it common for a phone's mobile data to stop functioning while the phone's normal phone reception works perfectly fine?

Do these functions use the same components to work?

Comment: Do you have Mobile Data enable in the network settings?  Are the APNs set up?  (And yes, you can definitely use voice and SMS without a data connection.)

Answer (score 0):

Not normal , check your phone params to be sure that you did not disable data , you can also dial `*#*#4636#*#*` to open the diagnostic menu then first item and scroll down to "preferred network" and check what is written.